# how to draw only straight lines using react recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I try to use react recharts. I need chart like this [chart with straight lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvJ8E.png)
But I can't draw the straight lines. I try to use  but something wrong

```
<Line  points={[{x:0, y:900}, {x:dataWithDay.lenght-1, y:900}]} stroke="gray" dot={false}/>
```

And not clear for me what does mean values in the array points. If I understand well x and y are coordinates of the XAxis and YAxis. This Line draw anything

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you mean [ReferenceLine](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/ReferenceLine).